# How I pass multiple parameters to a soap method using nusoap?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I have a single parametered mehod in soap web service fully working. What about passing another parameter?
PHP

Answer (score 0):

http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/10/using-php-and-nusoap-to-connect-to-web-services/

```
$param = array('param1' => 'stuff1',
                 'param2' => 'stuff2',
                 'param3' => 'stuff3',
                );
```